# vuex - is it possible to directly change state, even if not recommended?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

The documentation [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)
says,

> You cannot directly mutate the store's state. The only way to change a store's state is by explicitly **committing mutations**.

My question is, is that good practice, or is that how the internals of the Vuex state works?  In other words, is the Vuex state reactive in the same way Vue data is (it converts the JS object to an observable), or is it something else?

A similar question - could you directly change the state in an action instead of creating a mutation?  I know it's bad practice and it loses some of the traceability that following the conventions gives - but does it work?

Comment: _"is that good practice, or that's how the internals of the Vuex state work"_ <- it's both

Comment: If you're curious about the implementation, it's open source ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vuex

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I haven't tried it because I didn't know the answer and I thought that I would do others a favor by asking a question others might also have in the hopes of getting helpful answers.  But even if I did, if it works it may have just been a fluke based on some other factor - not because it always would work.

Comment: @Phil  - sorry but duh... ;)  I know it's open source. But that doesn't mean that I have the time or easy ability to figure it out.  If you want to turn your comment into answer (and even better put references) I can upvote it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Could you directly change the state in an action instead of creating a mutation? I know it's bad practice and it loses some of the traceability that following the conventions gives - but does it work?

Works, but throws a warning AND an error.

```
vue.js:584 [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

   (found in <Component>)
   warn @ vue.js:584
   ...

vue.js:1719 Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    at assert (VM260 vuex.js:103)
```

who knows what else might be broken after this.

See for yourself (notice the data updates in the template):

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
strict: true,
  state: {
    people: []
  },
  mutations: {
    populate: function (state, data) {
      //Vue.set(state, 'people', data);
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
    let self = this;
    this.$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/g07qh').then(function (response) {
      // setting without commit
      Vue.set(self.$store.state, 'people', response.data); 
      //self.$store.commit('populate', response.data)
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    });
  },
  computed: {
    datadata: function() {
      return this.$store.state.people
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-resource"></script>

<div id="app">
  Data: {{ datadata }}
</div>
```

> the Vuex state reactive in the same way Vue data is (it converts the js object to an observable), or is it something else?

Yes. Actually, that's Vue itself that makes the store objects reactive. From the [Mutations official docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html):

> #### Mutations Follow Vue's Reactivity Rules
>
> Since a Vuex store's state is made reactive by Vue, when we mutate the
> state, Vue components observing the state will update automatically.
> This also means Vuex mutations are subject to the same reactivity
> caveats when working with plain Vue:
>
> 1. Prefer initializing your store's initial state with all desired fields upfront.
> 2. When adding new properties to an Object, you should either:
>
> - Use `Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123)`, or
> - Replace that Object with a fresh one. For example, using the stage-3 [object spread
>   syntax](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) we can
>   write it like this:
>
>   ```
>       state.obj = { ...state.obj, newProp: 123 }
>   ```

So even within mutations code, if you overwrite observables or create new properties directly (by not calling `Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', newValue)`), the object won't be reactive.

### Follow up questions from comments (good ones!)

> So it seems the observable object is slightly different than the regular Vue data - changes are only allowed to happen from a mutation handler. Is that right?

They could be, but I don't believe they are. The docs and evidences (see below `vm.$watch` discussion below) point torward they being exactly the same as `data` objects, at least with regards to reaction/observable behaviors.

> How does the object "know" it was mutated from a different context?

This is a good question. Allow me to rephrase it:

> If calling `Vue.set(object, 'prop', data);` from within Vue throws an exception (see demo above), why calling `Vue.set(object, 'prop', data);` from within a mutation function doesn't?

The answer lies [within `Store.commit()`'s code](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/e821f1bf5b818992d7f34c03029ce2ded1f52a75/dist/vuex.js#L376). It executes the mutation code [through a `_withCommit()` internal function](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/e821f1bf5b818992d7f34c03029ce2ded1f52a75/dist/vuex.js#L376-L397).

All that [this `_withCommit()` does is it sets a flag `this._committing` to `true`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/e821f1bf5b818992d7f34c03029ce2ded1f52a75/dist/vuex.js#L498-L503) and **then** executes the mutation code (and returns  `_committing` to `false` after the exection).

The Vuex store is then [watching the states' variables](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/e821f1bf5b818992d7f34c03029ce2ded1f52a75/dist/vuex.js#L750) and if it notices (aka the watcher triggers) that the [variable **changed while the `_committing` flag was `false`** it throws the warning](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/e821f1bf5b818992d7f34c03029ce2ded1f52a75/dist/vuex.js#L752).

(Bonus: [do notice that vuex uses `vm.$watch`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/e821f1bf5b818992d7f34c03029ce2ded1f52a75/dist/vuex.js#L750)  --see [Vue's `vm.$watch` API docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) if you are not familiar with it -- to observe the variables, another hint that state's objects are the same as data objects - they rely on Vue's internals.)

Now, to prove my point, let's **"trick" vuex by setting `state._committing` to `true`** ourselves and then call `Vue.set()` from outside a mutator. As you can see below, **no warning** is triggered. Touché.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
strict: true,
  state: {
    people: []
  },
  mutations: {
    populate: function (state, data) {
      //Vue.set(state, 'people', data);
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
    let self = this;
    this.$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/g07qh').then(function (response) {
      // trick the store to think we're using commit()
      self.$store._committing = true;
      // setting without commit
      Vue.set(self.$store.state, 'people', response.data); 
      // no warning! yay!
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    });
  },
  computed: {
    datadata: function() {
      return this.$store.state.people
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-resource"></script>

<div id="app">
  Data: {{ datadata }}
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing -  thanks!  So it seems the observable object is slightly different than the regular Vue data - changes are only allowed to happen from a mutation handler.  Is that right?  How does the object "know" it was mutated from a different context?

Comment: Just give me a sec, I have a lead, let me confirm and will get back to you.

Comment: There you go. Thanks for asking, I'm actually quite happy with the result. Learned a lot! Let me know if it's good for you or anything else!

Comment: Thanks so much - that's really helpful and interesting.  It's good to note that you can disable this by setting strict to false for Vuex.  I'm also curious about the performance hit of this vuex watch with more data or lots of updates (not asking you to benchmark it - just thinking out loud :) .

Comment: I guess what has the greatest potential to be problematic, peformance-wise, is the rendering part. If you have tons of watched data that get updated frequently, they probably are being re-rendered somewhere. Considering you are not doing any extreme calculation involving the reactive values of the store, the rendering operation is certainly going to be the expensive part, in comparison to the mere "watching" logic.

Comment: So what's the correct way to replace the whole object already defined in the state?

Comment: Why I am not seeing this warning when I directly set `state.xxx`? Has the behaviour changed since this answer?

Comment: @XiaoPeng-ZenUML.com I dont think so. Are you changing the state from inside a mutation (and ***synchronously***)?

Answer (score 14):

I am going to make this very simple:

Because the state object is already reactive, you can completely avoid using getters and mutations. All of Vue’s templates, computed, watch, etc. will continue to work the same as if using a component’s data.  The store’s state acts as a shared data object.

But by doing so you will lose the ability to implement time-travel debugging, undo/redo, and setting breakpoints, because you will have circumvented the [command design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and encapsulation of a member by using methods.