# Vuex: Weird question on weird behavior of vuex. I need at least one mutation and a commit to update or assign to my store objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to set token to my `store.token` I know this is not a best option without using mutation but I'm doing something like this:

```
methods : {
        molestor(){
            const self = this;
            this.$store.state.token = "new token";
            this.$store.state.cleavage= "yes";
            this.$store.commit('settoken', "somethingrandom");
        },  
}
```

Then on my store.js:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state : {
        token : '',

    },
    mutations : {
        settoken(state,token){
            console.log(token);
        }
    }
});
```

Right now it works fine... it sets up. But when I remove the mutation from `store.js` or remove the commit on my `molester()` it wont assign the value to token. Why is this happening?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122648/vuex-is-it-possible-to-directly-change-state-even-if-not-recommended

Comment: Its really different. I dont get any errors. The thing is i dont need to `commit` a mutation which will set my value. I'm not setting my store data with mutation. I'm doing the normal way. When i remove the mutation which is not doing anything i'm unable to set store value. @AnaLizaPandac that is why i said weird in the first place. Thank you for your help

Comment: You just shouldn't be doing that: it's not how VueX is supposed to work, and you managing to get it to work might just be a quirk and there is no guarantee that it will work all the time. Just stick to using mutations to, as its name suggest, mutate the states on your VueX store.

Answer (score 2):

To set the value of state in store, we have to interact with Vuex api via mutations/commits.

By trying to set the state without a mutation, this goes against the design of Vuex (having a manageable store/state)

Typically trying to set state without mutations (say within an action) will throw an error, but I also believe that by getting the state via ‘$store.state’ will only return the state (and not return the instance of state)

This is done to maintain immutability throughout your application state

Comment: Whilst you're correct that mutations *should* be used for setting state. Setting state directly without a mutation works fine and will not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting to see the change appear in the Vue dev tools you won't see any changes to state unless they occur through a mutation or until another mutation is called.