# In Vue, without mutation if want to make state update then how i can make it?

Tags: vue.js

In vue, if want to update the state without mutation then how i can make it ? Make sure we do not want to used mutation.. Any idea then share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122648/vuex-is-it-possible-to-directly-change-state-even-if-not-recommended

Comment: similar, but want to know better way.

Comment: Do you mean in Vuex or are you just referring to treating objects as immutable within component data?

Comment: In vuex, i want to make

Answer (score 0):

As per [Vuex Mutations Documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) Mutations are only way to change state in Store. you cannot call mutation directly and you cannot update state without mutations.

Answer (score 0):

You can mutate state directly, it is not recommended but can be done, just access the property and mutate: `this.$store.myState['variable'] = someNewValue`